# Android, Kotlin. How to create a scaled bitmap and pass the drawable resource as "Bitmap src"?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I'm creating a scaled bitmap. It contains the following parameters (official documentation):

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

I can pass another bitmap object to the **"Bitmap src"** place, something like this:

```
val bitmapOjbect = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val srcbitmap: Bitmap? =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapObject, 10,10, true)
bitmapObject.eraseColor(Color.BLUE)

carsFragmentInterface?.processData(listofCars.apply {
    add(Car("Subaru", srcbitmap))
    })
carsFragmentInterface?.startUpdatingAdapter()
```

This code will create a blue square and display it in the Car object's ImageView.
But i don't want to create just a colored square. I want a picture to be displayed instead of the blue square.

So here's what i was trying to do:

```
val decodeResource = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context?.resources, R.drawable.picture)
val srcbitmap: Bitmap? =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeResource, 10,10, true)

carsFragmentInterface?.processData(listofCars.apply {
    add(Car("Subaru", srcbitmap))
    })
carsFragmentInterface?.startUpdatingAdapter()
```

And after this code update my ImageView doesn't display an image, it's just empty for some reason. Although some articles on **stackoverflow** contained posts where it was said that this code should work perfectly. I'm working with **API 23 (Marshmallow)**. Perhaps this code is outdated, or I'm doing something wrong.

I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: this should work. try to change R.drawable.picture to another

Comment: @Style-7 unfortunately it doesn't work. all i can see is empty imageview

Comment: I ask you to change image, may be problem of decoder

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same.